# Nodemailer - how add attachment to template email in jade

Tags: javascript, pug, nodemailer

I don't know how use embedded images in email, utilizing attachments.

I have in .js:

`var mailOptions = {
...
html: 'my html jade',
attachments: [{
    filename: 'image.png',
    path: '/picture/file',
    cid: 'myPicture' //same cid value as in the html img src
}]`

In jade file:

`...
     img(src="cid:myPicture")`

When i send my email ....
This not work. I have added attachment in the e-mail, but message do not have embedded images.

Comment: have you tried setting the full path for your image?

Comment: Where? in jade file?

Comment: No. In the `path` property of the attachment

Answer (score 1):

Whoa! Super old question. You've either figured it out or quit programming by now. When I ran into the same problem, Google led me here.

It all comes down to the path. I had to set the absolute path *including the file name*. So, in your case, it would all look like this:

```
var mailOptions = {
  // ...
  html: 'my html jade',
  attachments: [{
  filename: 'image.png',
  path: '/picture/file/image.png',
  cid: 'myPicture' //same cid value as in the html img src
}]
```

I can't speak for the `jade` stuff, but hopefully this will help some other Nodemailer.